# Removing a windows user from Builtin Users group

Tags: c#, windows

I created an User (say skumar) in Windows through the GUI/CLI, it is automatically added to the local Users group(Builtin\Users). Then I removed this User from the Windows Users group. 
I have this code which lists all the groups the current user belongs to:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
var groups = identity.Groups;
```

But this says the User (i.e. skumar) belongs to BUILTIN\USERS group. I have restarted the system but NO luck.

Comment: how did you removed the user from Users group?

Comment: I removed it from the GUI. Go to the Properties window of the User and move to the Tab "Member Of" and Delete the user from Users group.

Comment: You can't remove a user from their primary group, which by default is "Users".  I'm not sure whether there is any way to do this from the GUI.